# Android failed to connect to database

Tags: php, android, mysql, okhttp, mamp-pro

I am new in android, i wanna connect my android app to mysql database via php (I use MAMP-pro to create database). I don't know why the response is failed. In my php file, I insert a new record in my database table, but it doesn't add the new record to my database. Here is my code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    File cacheDirectory = new File(this.getCacheDir(),"http");
    int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDirectory, cacheSize);
    client.setCache(cache);
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://localhost:8888/myFirstPHP.php").build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
            updateTextView1();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.code() >= 200 || response.code() <= 300){
                ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
                InputStream inputStream = responseBody.byteStream();
                updateTextView();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the error exactly?

Comment: My guess is to debug your php and see if the request reaches that

Comment: change localhost in `http://localhost:8888/myFirstPHP.php` to your PHP-server's IP address or domain name

Comment: example: something like `http://192.168.xxx.yyy:8888/myFirstPHP.php` or `http://mydomain.xyz/myFirstPHP.php`

Comment: Thanks @Yazan it works well :) . I just wanna know this will work via real phone, or it has to be something else.

Comment: yes, it will work via real phone

Comment: @Yazan, sorry it works from a phone connected to the same wireless network, but not from a phone connected to another network, it is really strange, do you why?

Comment: yes, because you are using a local network IP, if you want to use it internet-public you will need to use/configure a public physical IP that can be accessed over the internet from all over the world. this includes obtain physical ip for your internet connection, configure it on the router/firewall to allow access for the server's PORT, and other configuration on the database server (allow remote access) for remote hosts. I HAVE TO WARN YOU if you expose your server over the internet you will have to be well secured and protected otherwise your database may get hacked